# Problem with simple armature opening a box

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/O1em_ijMvUk), trying to rig a simple armature to open the flaps of a box.

In the [section at 5m38](https://youtu.be/O1em_ijMvUk?t=338), he rotates the armature to bend a flap.

All of my flaps work fine, except for the front flap, which doesn't bend enough.  When the armature is rotated to 90 degrees, the flap only gets to about 45 degrees:

[image]

I've assigned and removed the vertex groups several times, but can't work out how to get it to work like all the other bones.  What am I doing wrong?

Blender file:
https://file.io/apJjRMPoi7w7

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  That behavior looks like the flap's vertices are also in the vertex group for one or more other bones.

Comment: added to the question - many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see this vertex is part of the vertex group called L while it should only be part of the vertex group called F:

[image]

So select all these vertices and remove them from the vertex group called L:

[image]

And also probably remove all these vertices from all groups:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!